# Calling function in the service from the service

Tags: angularjs

This is the code:

```
vm.getAllData = function (user_id) {
    alert(user_id);
}

usersService.getUser().then(function (user) {
    getAllData(user.id);
});
```

But when I do this it is working:

```
vm.getAllData = function (user_id) {
    alert(user_id);
}

getAllData(3);
```

What happens is that `getAllData(user.id)` is not getting called. Tried `vm.getAllData(user.id);` as well.

What is the proper way to call the function?

Comment: In what context are you calling it? From within another function in the service it should be this.getAllData(3);

Comment: @DanWeber, no luck (

Comment: You must be calling the service from another component right? There is no ngOnInit or anything like that in the service. I suppose you could do it in the constructor, but usually you'd call the service layer from another component, so it would trigger that function there.

Comment: @DanWeber, I edited the question to make it more elaborate.

Comment: Subscribe to the getAllData function to listen for response.

Comment: Please, add the constructor function from your service, and also the function for usersService.getUser() so that, I can tell if there is something missing.

Answer (score 0):

call like vm.getAllData(3);

or split declaration:

```
var getAllData = function (user_id) {
    alert(user_id);
}

vm.getAllData = getAllData;

usersService.getUser().then(function (user) {
    getAllData(user.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.getAllData = function (user_id) {
    alert(user_id);
}

usersService.getUser().then(function (user) {
    ̶g̶e̶t̶A̶l̶l̶D̶a̶t̶a̶(̶u̶s̶e̶r̶.̶i̶d̶)̶;̶
    vm.getAllData(user.id);
});
```

Comment: While this code may provide an answer, it'd be better if you can dedicate a few words to explain how it works.